# AngularJS update Service values when connected or disconnected to firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularjs-service, firebase-realtime-database

I wish to change the icon color when connected or disconnected to the firebase server. I got this far:

**HTML**

```
<button class="button button-icon ion-cloud" ng-style="dbConnectedStyle"></button>
```

**Controller**

```
firebaseRef.$loaded().then( function() {
  $scope.dbConnectedStyle = {'color': dbConnectStatus.color};
}
```

**Service**

```
.service('dbConnectStatus', function(firebaseRef){
  var status = false;
  var color = 'transparent';
  var connectedRef = firebaseRef.child(".info/connected");
  connectedRef.on("value", function(snap) {
    status = snap.val();
    if (status) {
      color = 'lightgrey';
      console.log("Connected to DB (" + color + ")" );
    } else {
      color = 'transparent';
      console.log("Disonnected to DB (" + color + ")" );
    }
  });
  return {
    'boolean': status,
    'color': color
  }
})
```

It change color the first time. But when disconnecting it doesn't change... seems like it's not two-way binding to the service. How do I achieve this?

---

## UPDATE

Tried to do a reference to the Service as an object rather than doing primitives assignments as explained in the good tutorial [A Tale of Frankenstein and Binding to Service Values in Angular.js](http://stsc3000.github.io/blog/2013/10/26/a-tale-of-frankenstein-and-binding-to-service-values-in-angular-dot-js/)

I changed the code to the following

**HTML**

```
<button class="button button-icon ion-cloud" 
        ng-style="dbConnectionStatus.connectionStyle">
        </button>
```

**Service**

```
.service('dbConnectStatus', function(firebaseRef, $rootScope){
  this.status = false;
  var styles = {
    'offlineStyle': {'color': 'red'},
    'onlineStyle': {'color': 'lightgrey'}
  };
  this.connectionStyle = styles.offlineStyle;

  firebaseRef.child(".info/connected")
    .on("value",
      function(snap) {
        this.status = snap.val();
        if (snap.val()) {
          console.log("Connected to DB.");
          this.connectionStyle = styles.onlineStyle;
          console.log(this.connectionStyle);
        } else {
          console.log("Disconnected to DB.");
          this.connectionStyle = styles.offlineStyle;
          console.log(this.connectionStyle);
        }
        console.log(this.status);
        $rootScope.$broadcast('dbConnection:changed');            
      }
    );

})
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.dbConnectionStatus = dbConnectStatus;
      $scope.$on('dbConnection:changed', function() {
        console.log("'on(...)' called. This is the $scope.dbConnectionStatus.connectionStyle:");
        $scope.dbConnectionStatus = dbConnectStatus;
        console.log($scope.dbConnectionStatus.connectionStyle);
        console.log("This is the dbConnectStatus.connectionStyle:");
        console.log(dbConnectStatus.connectionStyle);
      });
      $rootScope.$watch('dbConnectStatus', function (){
        $scope.dbConnectionStatus = dbConnectStatus;
      });
      //$rootScope.$apply();
```

I then reloaded the code and got this console message

[image: First time load]

I then turned off the connection

[image: Internet connection off]

I then turn on the connection

[image: Internet connection on]

It is clear to me that the service `dbConnectionStatus` isn't updated as a global variable in the way that I expected. I was on the assumption that a service is called once when the application is load and that assigning a scope variable to a service (object) is not a call but a reference...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Nothing to do with angular or firebase here. This is just how passing by value works in javascript. `dbConnectedStyle` does not reference `dbConnectStatus`'s color variable. It just copies the value

Comment: How would you pass the variable reference and not the value?

Comment: store the color in an object on the service. e.g. `var style = {color: 'transparent'}`. And reference the object on your controller

Comment: Isn't that already what I'm doing?

Comment: @rob tried to do your suggestion, but as you can see in the updated question I failed...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I worked in a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vyp76wj1/3/) using `$emit` and `$on` to handle the status changes inside the service. The main problem is that when going online the angular binding was not working properly so I needed to force an angular cycle with `$scope.$apply()`.

I started working on the first version of your code but made some refactoring. You can find the full code on the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vyp76wj1/3/) but the service and the controller look like the following:

### Service

```
.service('dbConnectStatus', function($rootScope){
  var status = false;
  var color = 'red';
  var self = {      
        startWatchingConnectionStatus: function(){
        var connectedRef = firebase.database().ref().child(".info/connected");
        connectedRef.on("value", function(snap) {
            console.log(snap.val());
            status = snap.val();
            if (status) {
                color = 'blue';
                console.log("Connected to DB (" + color + ")" );
            } else {
                color = 'red';
              console.log("Disonnected to DB (" + color + ")" );
              }
            $rootScope.$emit('connectionStatus:change', {style: {'color': color}, status: status}});
        });
      },
      getStatus: function(){
        return status;
      },
      getColor: function(){
        return color;
      }
  };
  return self;
})
```

### Controller

```
.controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', 'dbConnectStatus', '$rootScope',function($scope, dbConnectStatus, $rootScope) {

    dbConnectStatus.startWatchingConnectionStatus();

    $rootScope.$on('connectionStatus:change',  function currentCityChanged(event, value){
        $scope.color = value.style;
        //if changed to connected then force the $apply
        if(value.status === true){
            $scope.$apply();
        }
    });  
}]);
```

Let me know if there is anything that is still not clear.

Comment: Your suggestion of passing the style in the broadcast got me to a solution that works. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Inspired from @adolfosrs great answer I found the following solution to work for me.

**Service**

```
.service('dbConnectStatus', function(firebaseRef, $rootScope){
  // Initial setup
  var styles = {
    'offlineStyle': {'color': 'red'},
    'onlineStyle': {'color': 'skyeblue'}
  };

  // Functions to switch status
  var offline = function () {
    this.boolean = false;
    this.style = styles.offlineStyle;
  }
  var online = function () {
    this.boolean = true;
    this.style = styles.onlineStyle;
  }

  var get_status = function(){
    return {
      boolean: this.boolean,
      style: this.style
    }
  }

  // Read the firebase info and update when changed
  firebaseRef.child(".info/connected")
    .on("value", function(snap) {
        if (snap.val()) {
          online();
        } else {
          offline();
        }
        $rootScope.$emit('dbConnection:changed', get_status() );
    });
})
```

**Controller**

```
// Hide it before the status is known.
$scope.dbConnectionStatus = {'color': 'transparent'}; 
// Getting and reading status changes
$rootScope.$on('dbConnection:changed', function(event, status) {
    $scope.dbConnectionStatus = status.style;
    $scope.$apply();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get this working simply by storing the color in an object in the service and referencing it from the controller. e.g.

View

```
<button class="button button-icon ion-cloud" ng-style="dbStatusService.style"></button>
```

Controller

```
$scope.dbStatusService = dbConnectStatus;
```

Service

```
.service('dbConnectStatus', function(firebaseRef){
    var status = false;
    var style = {color: 'transparent'};
    var connectedRef = firebaseRef.child(".info/connected");
    connectedRef.on("value", function(snap) {
        status = snap.val();
        if (status) {
            style.color = 'lightgrey';
        } else {
            style.color = 'transparent';
        }
    });
    return {
        'boolean': status,
        'style': style
    }
});
```